# ArcMap annotation "disappears" when moved to the edge of the projection in map frame

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, editing, annotation

I have feature-linked annotations in a file GDB for a world map in Plate Carree projection.  When I edit annotations and move an annotation beyond the upper extent of the projection in the map frame (accidentally), the annotation "disappears."

It is still showing as "Placed" but now the fields for Shape Length and Shape Area are zero.  When I select the feature and Zoom to Selected, I am taken to a random place on the map.  I have tried panning or changing projection, but the issue seems to be that annotation feature is now infinitely small.

Unfortunately, edits were saved before this problem was realized.  Is there any way to fix this?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop v10.7.1